# Number of rows containing 2 of 5 specified values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
n1|n2|n3|n4|n5
 1| 5| 4| 7|26
26|80|75| 1|10
 5| 3| 2| 1|4
45|26|88| 3|66
88|48| 1|69|90
```

I'm trying to get the number of rows in which 2 of 5 specified values appear.
Example:
26, 1, and 88.
In the above table, 26 and 1 appear in 2 rows (1st and 2nd); 26 and 88 appear in 1 row (4th); 88 and 1 appear in 1 row (5th).

I can use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table
WHERE 1 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) OR 26 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) OR 88 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)
```

but this way I get rows containing only 1 number too.

Is there a fast way to do this in mySQL or should I build some function in PHP?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: just my opinion but I would attempt this in PHP, looping through the results of a simpler query and building a final array of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`in()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) returns 1 if the value exists and 0 if it doesn't, so you could add these up and look for 2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE ((1 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)) + (26 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)) + (88 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5))) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you construct a (temporary) `search` table to hold the values you wish to find:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE search (v INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO search VALUES (26),(1),(88);
```

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT   s1.v x, s2.v y, COUNT(*)
FROM     my_table
    JOIN search s1 ON s1.v IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)
    JOIN search s2 ON s2.v IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) AND s1.v < s2.v
GROUP BY x, y;
```

See it on [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8868/1/0).